# If $g$ is continuous and $g(1)=0$, then $x^ng(x)$ converges on $[0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

> Suppose $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function satisfying $g(1)=0$. Prove that the functions $f_n(x)=x^ng(x)$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. Hence or using Mean Value Theorem, prove that if $\int_0^1x^ng(x)dx=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ then $g$ is identically $0$.

First of all, I don't think the convergence is uniform. The pointwise limit is $0$. Now consider $\sup_{x\in[0,1)}x^n|g(x)|=c_n^n|g(c_n)|$ for some $c_n$ which depends on $n$. The supremum is attained as the function $x^n|g(x)|$ is continuous. Now, as I vary $n$, $c_n$ varies and thus, we cannot conclude anything I think.

Secondly, I don't understand how the first part can imply the second part of the question. I obtained the second part using Bernstein Polynomials (Weierstrauss Approximation Theorem) using the fact that these polynomials are uniformly convergent to $g$. I tried using Mean Value Theorem but could not proceed further.

But this lands in a new question:

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous non-zero function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$. Then is it true that $f$ cannot have infinitely many roots in $[a,b]$?

If I know the answer to this question, I can answer the second part of the original question. The reasoning being that for every $n$, using Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c_n\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c_n)\int_0^1x^ndx=0$ giving $f(c_n)=0$ for all $n$. I want to show this is a contradiction if $f$ is non-zero.

Comment: Are you familiar with a theorem that says if $f_{n}$ are continuous and converge on a compact set to a continuous function $f$, then they converge uniformly?  (I think this is Dini's theorem).  The $f_{n}$'s here are continuous, and defined on the compact set $[0,1]$, and they converge pointwise to the continuous function $0$, so the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Yes Dini saves the day here. You missed the condition that $f_n$ need to be monotonic, but that is okay as here monotonicity is preserved.

Comment: @user46944 Dini theorem is probably too complex (especially if you forget some arguments!)

Comment: A bit late, but ... +1 for presenting your thoughts and previous progress in the question.

Comment: @LandonCarter Could you tell where you found this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @layman how this function is monotonic?

Answer (score 3):

For the first part:
let $\epsilon > 0$.
As $g$ is continuous there is $1 > \delta > 0$ such as 
$$x > 1-\delta \implies |g(x)| < \frac\epsilon2
$$

As $g$ is bounded by some $M$, 
$$
|x^n g(x)| \le \sup_{x \le 1-\delta} |x^n g(x)|+
 \sup_{x < 1-\delta} |x^n g(x)| 
\le M(1-\delta)^n +  \frac\epsilon2 \le \epsilon
$$for $n > \frac{\log M - \log \epsilon }{\log (1-\delta)}$ big enough.

Comment: And what about deriving that $g=0$ given $\int x^ng(x)dx=0$ for all $n$? Could you find out using MVT?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question: take $$f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\\f(x)=x\sin\left(\frac 1x\right).$$
It is continuous on $[0,1]$ and it has infinitely many roots on the same interval.